# Google App Engine Deployment fais with Intellij idea

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, web-deployment

I am developing a Google App Engine application with IntelliJ idea, the app is running successfully on local machine but when I need to deploy it on my cloud it fails and I get the following error :

```
  Password for myemail@gmail.com: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found
Unable to update app: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found
please see the log
```

Having checked the log file the content was:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ClientLoginServerConnection.getAuthToken(ClientLoginServerConnection.java:250)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ClientLoginServerConnection.authenticate(ClientLoginServerConnection.java:86)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ClientLoginServerConnection.doHandleSendErrors(ClientLoginServerConnection.java:120)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:296)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:173)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:139)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:467)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1347)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:332)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:213)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:124)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:120)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1834)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.connect(AbstractServerConnection.java:133)
at
```

I also have searched for this error and I think this link should address this issue

[Issue 12898:   Some AppEngine deploys are failing](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12898)

I uploaded a picture from the setting up App Engine deployment,

**Question** : What exactly should I change in order to get it working and successfully deploying on the App Engine Server?

[image: Intellij idea App Engine Deployment Setting]

Comment: password login is deprecated, I think it's no longer supported. Never use intellij, but the easiest is to run it from command line :P

Comment: @marcadian even when I try to do it with command line with this command appengine-java-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd  update <war-location> it asks for email and password and then gives me back the same error so somewhere I have to change the  login method

Comment: Update your SDK! the latest one should only have oauth2

Comment: @marcadian its version is 1.9.4 so I think its already the latest one

Comment: Latest one is 1.9.38, 1.9.4 is from 2014! https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by `appcfg.cmd [options] update <war-location>` and adding the argument `--oauth2` to the command it should have been also solved by updating the `sdk` versionas mentioned in comments